# Verify role with a custom UserStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Source: https://github.com/jhonduck22/ApiExample23231232

I have an authorization which check the JWT token (the "Administrator" role), but now I want advanced roles and more checking the database with Dapper instead of saving the roles in the access token, so I have created a custom UserStore. The problem is when I call the controller, the controller returns Not Found instead of checking the role.

I have the next controller which return "200 Ok" without [Authorize], and "404 Not Found" with [Authorize]

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles = "TestingIdentity")]
public IActionResult IdentityTest()
{
    return Ok("Responsee");
}
```

UserStore

```
public class UserStore<IdentityUser> :
    IUserStore<IdentityUser>
{
    // ...
}
```

UserRoleStore

```
public class UserRoleStore<IdentityUser> :
    IUserRoleStore<IdentityUser>
{
    // ...
    public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(TUser user, string roleName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
```

IdentityUser

```
public class IdentityUser
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Mail { get; set; }
}
```

Startup

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
.AddUserStore<UserStore>()
.AddRoleStore<UserRoleStore>();

services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
{
    auth
    .AddPolicy("AdministratorOnly", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireRole("Administrator")
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build());

    auth
    .AddPolicy("TestingIdentityOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole("TestingIdentity")
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser());
});
```

[image]

Comment: `404 Not Found != 401\403` are you sure you're getting a 404 ? if you do - means you're not even getting to the controller. try debugging the store with a breakpoint to make sure

Comment: @Stavm Yes, I'm getting a 404 with Postman. If I purge the Authorize attribute, I get a correct answer. I have a breakpoint in IsInRoleAsync, but it doesn't stop in the method. I don't know if I must implement another interface or what

Comment: You're not telling the DI system about your custom `IUserRoleStore` implementation - You think you are because you're using `AddUserStore`, but that [only registers the `IUserStore` interface](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/release/2.0/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core/IdentityBuilder.cs#L109).

Comment: @KirkLarkin I have updated my post and moved the IUserRoleStore implementation to another class and added the inyection with .AddRoleStore. But I'm getting 404 Not Found anyway.

Comment: Can you provide a simple repro project?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I can't validate now the first role in the token. Two roles (token and userstore) are broken now.

Comment: @KirkLarkin https://github.com/jhonduck22/ApiExample23231232

Comment: Using your repro, Adem's solution works and results in a 200 OK. If you'd like a more detailed explanation, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Putting 'Policy', I receive 404 Not Found

Comment: @KirkLarkin I have added a screenshot in the post

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I didn't

Comment: Did you see the pull request on your Github repo?

Comment: @KirkLarkin Yes. I receive 404 Not Found